# Length of Array within Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object that I am pushing some ints, strings and arrays into an array. And I want to get the length of the array that is within said array.

This is my code

```
var all_categories = [];

        all_categories.push({
            title: theTitle,
            id: theId,
            sub: subcategories
        });
```

Now I know that all_categories.length is the general way of getting the length and I believe that I can't run `all_categories[0].sub[0].length` will not work because the function does not exist.

Suggestions for a solution or work around?

Comment: what you want, the total subcategories or only within one all_category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your statement `all_categories[0].sub[0].length` refers to the length of the `first` element of array named `sub`.

In order to see length of the array you should call:

```
all_categories[0].sub.length
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `subcategories` is the array you want the length of, take out the second `[0]`. You aren't trying to get the length of the first subcategory, you're trying to get the number of subcategories.